# Extend Ofbiz EditProduct form

Tags: erp, ofbiz

I am trying to add a material field to the EditProduct form. I have made a plugin (ExtendDataModel) with the sole purpose of doing extensions to existing modules. My entitymodel.xml works and looks like this:

```
<extend-entity entity-name="Product">
   <field name="material" type="name"/>
</extend-entity>
```

It works great, and if I manually add it to the EditProduct form I of can see, add, and edit.

I haven't met with success in trying to shift over to my ExtendDataModelForm.xml:

```
<form name="EditProduct" extends="EditProduct" extends-resource="component://product/widget/catalog/ProductForms.xml">
    <field name="material" title="material"><display/><text size="30" maxlength="255"/></field>
</form>
```

It does not show up on the form when I go to Create New Product.
Ideally I'd like to add this to `<field-group title="${uiLabelMap.CommonMeasures}">` or `<field-group>`

Many Thanks!

I tried following the guide at
[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/48792051/2015_ApacheCon_Reduced.pdf?api=v2](How to Avoid Common Mistakes inMistakes in OFBizOFBiz Development)

Answer (score 0):

Is the screen in your plugin referring to your form in the plugin?

Can't you see anything in log?

(Weird, I tried 3 times to add "Hi Ken," at the top of the answer, it always disappears)